# Visibility Expression in Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have 3 reports currently designed on Report builder 3 that run at the same time but I want to only show each report when it is selected in the Select Report Parameter.

I know I have to go into the Chart Properties and select Visibility based on an expression but I have no idea how to construct the expression.

The Parameter includes:

Occupancy
PitchNightsSold
Capacity

I thought all I needed to do is write the following expression:

```
=IIf(Parameters!WhichReport.Value = "Occupancy", true, false)
```

But it doesn't seem to work, can you help?

Comment: Hi Ravinder, It does work but something is happening that I don't know how to fix, when I click on the Occupancy in the Parameter I am expecting to only see the Occupancy report but fro some reason I get the PitchNightsReport and Capacity reports instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the **visibility** property, you have to give the expression to **hide** the component. So you have to give `true` if you want to **hide** and `false` if you want to **show** the component. Change the expression to

`=IIf(Parameters!WhichReport.Value = "Occupancy", false, true)`

Comment: This was driving me nuts. Thank you!